# how to implement automatic and manual slider using jquery and also pause the slider on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have implemented **automatic and manual image slider together**. But I also want to **pause the automatic sliding on hover**. How can i do this. Here is the code snippet. No external libraries other than jQuery.

```
var slideIndex = 0;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

showSlides();

function showSlides() {    
    var i;    
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
    setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 5 seconds
}

function currentSlide(no) {
    var i;    
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    slideIndex = no;
    slides[no-1].style.display = "block";
}

function plusSlides(n) {
  var newslideIndex = slideIndex + n;
  if(newslideIndex < 4 && newslideIndex > 0){
     currentSlide(newslideIndex);
  }
}
```